# Как очистить ListView и заполнить его новыми данными

Tags: c#, xamarin

Доброго времени суток. помогите пожалуйста, как можно в Xamarin Portable в ListView при клике на элемент убрать старые данные и передать ему новый список данных?

```
public class FaculListView : ListView
{
    // Создаем коллекцию динамических данных, обеспечивающих при получении уведомлений и удалении элементов или обновлении всего списка.
    public ObservableCollection<FaculitesAndInstitutesCommerciaItem> FaculitesAndInstitutesCommerciaItems { get; set; }

    // Указываем ссылку на получение и разбор данных Json формат.
    private const string URLReitingCommerciaFI = "http://modules/mobile.php?action=get_all_department";

    public FaculListView()
    {
        RowHeight = 50;

        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand; 

        BackgroundColor = Color.White; 

        // Передаем в коллекцию новый список ячеек.
        FaculitesAndInstitutesCommerciaItems = new ObservableCollection<FaculitesAndInstitutesCommerciaItem>();

        GetAllReitingCommerciaFacultiesAndInstitutes();

        // DataTemplate отображает данные из коллекций объектов в ListView.
        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(FaculitesAndInstitutesCommerciaItem));

        // Делаем нажатие на один из элементов в списке и переходим на новый ListView.
        ItemTapped += (sender, args) =>
        {
           //указываем все элементы которые хранит в себе id и name args.Item as FaculitesAndInstitutesCommerciaItem
            var IdCommerciaFaculitiesAndInstitutes = args.Item as FaculitesAndInstitutesCommerciaItem;
            if (IdCommerciaFaculitiesAndInstitutes == null)
                return;


           SelectedItem = null;
        };

    }

    // Асинхронный запрос на данных в Json.
    public async Task GetAllReitingCommerciaFacultiesAndInstitutes()
    {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(URLReitingCommerciaFI);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
            {
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectCommerciaFI>(response);
                foreach (var commerciaFaculitesAndInstitutes in data.FaculitesInstitutesCommerciaItems)
                {
                    FaculitesAndInstitutesCommerciaItems.Add(commerciaFaculitesAndInstitutes);
                }
                ItemsSource = FaculitesAndInstitutesCommerciaItems;
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: очистить *ListView*  - `listView.setAdapter(null)` или `listView.clear()`, а добавить с помощью `ArrayAdapter`, загляните сюда [Populating a ListView With Data](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/)

Comment: Это подходит только для Android если не ошибаюсь, а как это все делать на три мобильные платформы Xamarin From (Portable) с единым кодом C#?

Comment: Дополните Ваш вопрос. Добавьте немного кода, опишите более детально, что Вы делаете и что у Вас не получается. Вы говорите, что *Это подходит только для `Android `* - а Вы проверили? Если Вы ждете, что за Вас здесь кто-то напишет программу, то я не думаю, что это произойдет, а вот если Вы покажете, что Вы пытаетесь сделать - Вам помогут решить возникшие проблемы.

Comment: Если открыть ссылку которую вы кинули "Populating a ListView With Data" то там сказано Android а не Xamarin Forms (Portable).

Вот пример кода.
А если написать более детально, то могу перефразировать свой вопрос, хотя я описал четко в вопросе в чем проблема.

Comment: Вопрос дополнили - это хорошо, да, писал как-то под Android и там работало. Гляньте вот тут: [Xamarin.Forms ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за внимание, вот решение данной проблемы:

```
        // Делаем нажатие на один из элементов в списке и переходим на новый список
        ItemTapped += (sender, position) =>
        {
            var IdCommercia = position.Item as DepartmentReitingCommercialItemsViewCell;
            if (IdCommercia == null)
                return;

            // Если следующий список не
            if (NextListID != 2) {
                GetAllSpecialtyAndEntrants(IdCommerciaMGPPK);
                NextListID++;
            }

            SelectedItem = null;
        };

    // Функция которая обновляет список до отделениев на коммерческой основе МГППК
    async void onRefresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = (ListView)sender; // Делаем указатель на список
        ViewCellDepartmentCommerciaItems.Clear(); // Очищаем коллекцию списка
        await Task.Delay(3000); // Делаем задержку ввиде анимаций
        await GetAllReitingCommeciaDepartment(); //  Загружаем новые данные
        NextListID = 0; // Возврощаем список к нулевому значению
        list.IsRefreshing = false; // Убераем загрузку
    }

    // Асинхронный запрос на получение всех Специальностей, Поступающих и Информация об поступающих
    public async Task GetAllSpecialtyAndEntrants(DepartmentReitingCommercialItemsViewCell Item)
    {
        ViewCellDepartmentCommerciaItems.Clear(); // Очищаем список для получение следующих данных
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var id = Item.id;
        Debug.WriteLine("URL: " + id);

        // Если список равен нулю, то делаем запрос данных на все специальности.
        if (NextListID == 0) {
            var URLSpecialty = URLReitingCommerciaSpecialty + id;
            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(URLSpecialty);
            Debug.WriteLine("URL: " + URLSpecialty);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
            {
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectReitingCommerciaMGPPK>(response);
                foreach (var commerciaSpecialty in data.ViewCellDepartmentReitingCommercialItems)
                {
                    ViewCellDepartmentCommerciaItems.Add(commerciaSpecialty);
                }
                ItemsSource = ViewCellDepartmentCommerciaItems;
            }
        }
}
```